# DNS Round Robin failover doesn't work with mqtt.js

Tags: node.js, dns, mqtt, failover

I have a NodeJS Application that uses mqtt.js to connect to an emqx cluster.

The MQTT cluster contains of 2 nodes which I try to provide failover for using DNS Round Robin. So I have 1 A-Record (let's say mqtt.example.com) which points to 2 IPs (IP1 and IP2). When both nodes are online also my NodeJS application connects fine and subscribes to the selected topics.

Now on the MQTT nodes I can see what node the application is connected to. When I now stop the node that the application is connected to I expect that it would (sooner or later) fail over to the second active node.

I tested also with Loraserver (Which connected to MQTT) as well as the Node Red implementation of MQTT and both immediately connect to the active node when I stop the node they're connected to.

However my NodeJS application with mqtt.js keeps trying to connect to the node which I just stopped and doesn't try to connect to the active one.

Scenario explanation:

1. I have 2 Active nodes, IP1 and IP2
2. I connect Loraserver, Node Red and NodeJS to mqtt.example.com
3. All 3 applications connect to IP1
4. I stop IP1 node by shutting down the emqx process
5. Loraserver and Node Red will immediately connect to IP2 automatically
6. NodeJS with mqtt.js however keeps showing me error message

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

with IP1 and doesn't fail over to IP2 (Kept it running for about 20 minutes and nothing happened. DNS lease time is set to 5 minutes if that's of any relavance)

How can I achiever failover using DNS Round Robing for an application using mqtt.js?
Thanks for any help

EDIT: As requested, added the testing code:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const tls = require('tls');
const MQTTTOPIC = 'test/upload';
const BROKER_URL = 'tls://mqtt.example.com';
const BROKER_PORT = '8883';
const MQTTUSER = 'username';
const MQTTPASS = 'password';

var mqttoptions = {
    clientId: MQTTUSER,
    port: BROKER_PORT,
    keepalive: 60,
    username: MQTTUSER,
    password: MQTTPASS
};

var client = mqtt.connect(BROKER_URL, mqttoptions);
client.on('connect', mqtt_connect);
client.on('reconnect', mqtt_reconnect);
client.on('error', mqtt_error);
client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived);
client.on('close', mqtt_close);

function mqtt_connect() {
    console.log("Connecting MQTT");
    client.subscribe(MQTTTOPIC, mqtt_subscribe);
}

function mqtt_subscribe(err, granted) {
    console.log("Subscribed to " + MQTTTOPIC);
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
}

function mqtt_reconnect(err) {
    console.log("Reconnect MQTT");
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
    client = mqtt.connect(BROKER_URL, mqttoptions);
}

function mqtt_error(err) {
    console.error("MQTT Error!");
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
}

function after_publish() {
    //do nothing
}

function mqtt_close() {
    console.warn("Close MQTT");
}

function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message, packet) {
    console.log("Message: " + message + " --- Received on Topic " + topic);
}
```

EDIT 2:
In case it matters, I'm running the code with pm2

EDIT 3: 
Plus the complete log output:

```
17|LOCALTE | Connecting MQTT
17|LOCALTE | Subscribed to test/upload
17|LOCALTE | Close MQTT
17|LOCALTE | Reconnect MQTT
17|LOCALTE | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED IP1:8883
17|LOCALTE |     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
17|LOCALTE |     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1057:20)
17|LOCALTE |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1096:14)
17|LOCALTE | MQTT Error!
17|LOCALTE | { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED IP1:8883
17|LOCALTE |     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1034:11)
17|LOCALTE |     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1057:20)
17|LOCALTE |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1096:14)
17|LOCALTE |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
17|LOCALTE |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
17|LOCALTE |   syscall: 'connect',
17|LOCALTE |   address: 'IP1',
17|LOCALTE |   port: 8883 }
17|LOCALTE | Close MQTT
17|LOCALTE | Reconnect MQTT
[...]
```

Comment: Given that Node-RED uses the mqtt.js library to implement it's MQTT nodes this shouldn't be a library problem. Edit the question to show the code you are using so we can see if there is anything obvious.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Added my code I used for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should not be calling `connect()` in the `on.('reconnect')` callback. The library will handle all of this for you.

```
...
function mqtt_reconnect(err) {
    console.log("Reconnect MQTT");
    if (err) { console.error(err); }
}
...
```

If it still doesn't work once you've removed this, as a work around you can list a group of servers that the library will round robin on it's own.

```
var mqttoptions = {
    clientId: MQTTUSER,
    port: BROKER_PORT,
    keepalive: 60,
    username: MQTTUSER,
    password: MQTTPASS
    servers:[
        {
            protocol: 'mqtts',
            host: 'ip-address-1',
            port: 8883
        },
        {
            protocol: 'mqtts',
            host: 'ip-address-2',
            port: 8883
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Changing mqtt_reconnect results in the same error. I know about the possibility to enter multiple servers but with plain IP addresses instead of the url also mqtts wouldn't work anymore, right? So I'd have to fallback to mqtt via VPN (would work but it would be even better if I could get it running with mqtts so I don't have the VPN as a single point of failure).

Comment: Decided to go for the solution to add multiple servers in the servers section of the client and expose mqtt without ssl via vpn in the end. Guess I can accept the answer since the workaround works fine so far (Still the VPN as spof annoys me) and I didn't get any clue why the DNS failover is not working